# Compile bash for android

Tags: android, bash, build, arm

I compiled bash 4.1 static build for android using NDK.While compiling I added this changes because of the errors.

> commented out fdprintf function from externs.h file
>   added #define HAVE_MKFIFO 1 to config.h file

Finaly I got

> undefined reference to "setgrent","getgrent","endgrent" from bashline.c and to "setpwent" from complete.c 
>   So I commented where they called.

Finally bash was compiled and when I tried to run it on my device,It worked but giving errors like when run pwd it didn't give proper folder.
And always I run a command there is a line telling `bash : precmd command not found`.
How to fix this

Comment: is compiling the bash yourself a requirement, or do you "just want to have" a bash compiled for ARM? if the second, you can just download one (maybe from archlinuxarm repos). If the first you can have a look at these tutorials: http://www.floyd.ch/?p=330 http://roycormier.net/2010/11/03/how-to-cross-compile-bash-for-android/

Comment: @RafaelT The 2 links you provided talk of using toolchains other than the one provided by the Android NDK, but the question is about building bash using the Android NDK.